# Test cases where Axios errors need to be handled differently, using Jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, jestjs, axios

Assuming that I have the following function, in which I want to handle different axios erroneous responses in different ways.

```
  async fetchData() {
    const data = {...};

    const response = await axios.post('endpoint_here', data)
      .catch((error) => {
        if (error.code === SomeKindOfError) {
          throw new SomeKindOfError(error.message);
        }

        if (error.code === AnotherKindOfError) {
          throw new AnotherKindOfError(error.message);
        }

        throw new Error(error.message);
      });

    return response.data;
  }
```

How can I test all these different cases in my test using Jest ?

At the moment my test is this:

```
test('test SomeKindOfError', async () => {
  axios.post.mockRejectedValueOnce(new SomeKindOfError('There was an error.'));

  await expect(fetchData())
    .rejects
    .toThrowError(new SomeKindOfError('There was an error.'));
});
```

The above test is a pass, but it is nothing close to what a proper test for this function should be.

I would want to be able to check what the error returned from Axios is, and accordingly test that my own custom made errors get thrown.

Ideally, a way of mocking the Axios error response that will allow me to cover all the different cases in my tests, something like the following:

```
  test('test SomeKindOfError', async () => {
    axios.post.mockImplementation(() => Promise.reject({
      error: { code: SomeKindOfError.code },
    }));

    await expect(fetchData())
      .rejects
      .toThrowError(new SomeKindOfError('There was an error.'));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, the solution was as simple as this:

```
test('test SomeKindOfError', async () => {
  axios.post.mockRejectedValueOnce({ code: SomeKindOfError });

  await expect(fetchData())
    .rejects
    .toThrowError(new SomeKindOfError('There was an error.'));
});
```